# MAMP installation change password

Tags: password

I changed the root user password in phpMyAdmin and now it cannot connect to the database. Does anyone know where, in the MAMP folder structure, where to hardcode the new password in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin`, there is a file named `config.inc.php`.

Inside of that file in your favorite text editor, you should be able to search for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']` and then modify the text in single quotes. (Which is 'root' by default.) Change that to whatever you changed your password to, ensure it's quoted as necessary, and refresh. You should instantly be connected!